# Import GeoTIFF into MapInfo - why "control points", and how to batch-create TAB files?

Tags: raster, mapinfo, geotiff-tiff

I have 20 GeoTIFFs (produced by gdal-merge of JPG/JGW-filepair hi-res aerial photographs) in total for this job; several hundred, overall for current and pending projects.

These files open without incident in QGIS and ArcGIS: drag'n'drop the file into a workspace, and both suites even detect the idiosyncratic deprecated projection (EPSG 3785 - not my choice) and put the images in the right spot on a map.

To try and open the identical file in MapInfo Pro 12.5 I amend MAPINFOW.PRJ to take account of it ignoring the (deprecated) existence of EPSG 3785, but still the 'Open Table' command (since when is a TIFF a 'table'?) acts as if I'm opening a file with no geodata at all. It wants me to pick three points on each image, type in the co-ordinates manually for each point, and then it will consider my request to add the image.

If MapInfo wants its 'TAB' file in order to perform the function of adding a geoTIFF raster layer to a map, how do I go about generating such a file (preferably in a batch)?

Comment: How did you add coordinate system to MAPINFOW.PRJ ? Did you add \p3785 at the very end of the string that represented name of CRS ? For example : "Popular Visualization CRS\p3857", 10, 157, 7, 0

Comment: @sys49152 - yes, exactly that string. MapInfo behaved like a decent piece of software once I created TFW files (to replicate the geoinfo that was already embedded in the TIFs) using gdal's listgeo utility.

Comment: I have some GeoTIFFs and tried just now to open it in v12.5 and have no problems at all, it automatically creates TAB files.

Comment: Yeah, I have come across a few GeoTIFF "versions" as well that MapInfo Pro can't read the registration information from. Not really sure why as other works just fine.

Comment: GT, would you be able to share one of your files? I would like to understand why MapInfo Pro doesn't see these as GeoTIFFs

Answer (score 2):

Using an answer from [Mike T](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/1872/mike-t) to [Creating TFW and PRJ files for folder of GeoTIFF files?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9421/creating-tfw-and-prj-files-for-folder-of-geotiff-files), I used `listgeo` to create TFW files to replicate the geodata that **already exists in the TIFs**.

```
listgeo -tfw x.tif  # FTW
```

Once I did that, MapInfo opened it.