# How to get gdal_translate to create world file for GeoTIFF

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, gdal-translate, world-file

Am trying to recreate "gdal... -co worldfile=yes"

However whenever I do I get error: "Warning 6: driver GTiff does not support creation option worldfile"

Though I think it may be working anyway. Any ways to prevent error message, or workarounds?

Comment: How about the accepted answer of [Creating TFW and PRJ files for folder of GeoTIFF files?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9421/creating-tfw-and-prj-files-for-folder-of-geotiff-files)

Answer (score 7):

"WORLDFILE=YES" is a [jpeg creation option](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_jpeg.html), not a tiff option.

The creation option you want is `TFW=YES`

```
gdal_translate -co "TFW=YES" infile outfile
```

See the [geotiff documentation](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_gtiff.html).

Comment: Should I add it to "-co worldfile=yes" string? Is the "infile outfile" needed also?

Comment: Thanks Luke. Just FYI I have been using the worldfile command successfully so far, in fact the only successful method. It creates a .wld file, which I manually rename to tfw or jgw.
Would be nice to have a string for warping and tfw all in one. But when I try to add extra commands into the dialogue (convert) it gives a "too many commands" error message. Anyway, thanks for this